# Difference between `open` and `io.BytesIO` in binary streams

Tags: python, io, stream

I'm learning about working with streams in Python and I noticed that the [IO docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) say the following:

> The easiest way to create a binary stream is with open() with 'b' in the mode string:
>
> `f = open("myfile.jpg", "rb")`
>
> In-memory binary streams are also available as BytesIO objects:
>
> `f = io.BytesIO(b"some initial binary data: \x00\x01")`

What is the difference between `f` as defined by `open` and `f` as defined by `BytesIO`. In other words, what makes a "In-memory binary stream" and how is that different from what `open` does?

Answer (score 192, accepted):

For simplicity's sake, let's consider writing instead of reading for now.

So when you use `open()` like say:

```
with open("test.dat", "wb") as f:
    f.write(b"Hello World")
    f.write(b"Hello World")
    f.write(b"Hello World")
```

After executing that a file called `test.dat` will be created, containing 3x `Hello World`. The data wont be kept in memory after it's written to the file (unless being kept by a name).

Now when you consider `io.BytesIO()` instead:

```
with io.BytesIO() as f:
    f.write(b"Hello World")
    f.write(b"Hello World")
    f.write(b"Hello World")
```

Which instead of writing the contents to a file, it's written to an in memory buffer. In other words a chunk of RAM. Essentially writing the following would be the equivalent:

```
buffer = b""
buffer += b"Hello World"
buffer += b"Hello World"
buffer += b"Hello World"
```

*In relation to the example with the with statement, then at the end there would also be a `del buffer`.*

The key difference here is optimization and performance. `io.BytesIO` is able to do some optimizations that makes it faster than simply concatenating all the `b"Hello World"` one by one.

Just to prove it here's a small benchmark:

- Concat:  1.3529 seconds
- BytesIO: 0.0090 seconds

```
import io
import time

begin = time.time()
buffer = b""
for i in range(0, 50000):
    buffer += b"Hello World"
end = time.time()
seconds = end - begin
print("Concat:", seconds)

begin = time.time()
buffer = io.BytesIO()
for i in range(0, 50000):
    buffer.write(b"Hello World")
end = time.time()
seconds = end - begin
print("BytesIO:", seconds)
```

Besides the performance gain, using `BytesIO` instead of concatenating has the advantage that `BytesIO` can be used in place of a file object. So say you have a function that expects a file object to write to. Then you can give it that in-memory buffer instead of a file.

The difference is that `open("myfile.jpg", "rb")` simply loads and returns the contents of `myfile.jpg`; whereas, `BytesIO` again is just a buffer containing some data.

Since `BytesIO` is just a buffer - if you wanted to write the contents to a file later - you'd have to do:

```
buffer = io.BytesIO()
# ...
with open("test.dat", "wb") as f:
    f.write(buffer.getvalue())
```

*Also, you didn't mention a version; I'm using Python 3. Related to the examples: I'm using the with statement instead of calling `f.close()`*

Comment: Great answer; Question mentions `in memory stream` and you've referred to `in memory buffer`. Is there a difference in Python? It would be worth addressing briefly. From an English semantic perspective, `stream` implies a continuous flow of bits from source to sink (pushing from source), where buffer implies a cache of bits in the source ready for rapid fetching of chunks or pieces from the source (the sink pulling from the source).

Comment: I ran the small benchmark on my machine and got similar result using Python3.5, however, when I use Python 2.7, the "Concat" and "BytesIO" takes similar time, "Concat" is even slightly better. Anything wrong? this makes me confused.

Comment: @Vallentin, sorry, you are wrong when you said "open("myfile.jpg", "rb") simply loads and returns the contents of myfile.jpg", see rhis `import io
f = open("myfile.jpg", "rb")
<class '_io.BufferedReader'>
>>> isinstance(f, io.BufferedIOBase)
True 
`

Comment: Great answer, glad you even covered how to write the buffer back out to a file as needed!

Answer (score 36):

Using `open` opens a file on your hard drive. Depending on what mode you use, you can read or write (or both) from the disk.

A `BytesIO` object isn't associated with any real file on the disk. It's just a chunk of memory that behaves like a file does. It has the same API as a file object returned from `open` (with mode `r+b`, allowing reading and writing of binary data).

`BytesIO` (and it's close sibling `StringIO` which is always in text mode) can be useful when you need to pass data to or from an API that expect to be given a file object, but where you'd prefer to pass the data directly. You can load your input data you have into the `BytesIO` before giving it to the library. After it returns, you can get any data the library wrote to the file from the `BytesIO` using the `getvalue()` method. (Usually you'd only need to do one of those, of course.)