# Including Google Cloud SDK in virtualenv using Python Flexible Environment

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, virtualenv, python-imaging-library

I want to use the google.appengine.api images package but I do not know how to install the tools for virtualenv. The package works fine when I use dev_appserver.py on my normal environment but when I use the flexible environment with flask it cannot find the package. Is there a way to add the images library into my virtualenv?

When I try using Pillow to resize the image before I uploaded it to the server but when I would do that the image would arrive in the cloud storage at 0B.

```
if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
    filename = '%s_%s.jpg' % (item.id, len(item.photos))
    # Resize file using pillow
    image = Image.open(file)
    image.thumbnail((300,300)
    resized_image = io.BytesIO()
    image.save(resized_image, format='JPEG')
    # if I did a image.show() here the image would 
    # properly be shown resized
    gcs = storage.Client()
    bucket = gcs.get_bucket(CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET)
    blob = bucket.blob(filename)

    blob.upload_from_file(resized_image,
        content_type=file.content_type)
    # I would then view the image in the bucket and it shows up as 0 bytes
    # and blank
    # If I just use the regular file it uploads fine.
```

Comment: Can you check if `resized_image` contains what you expect?

Comment: Maybe `blob.upload_from_file(resized_image.get_value(),...`?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42800250/difference-between-open-and-io-bytesio-in-binary-streams

Comment: So i added this line `Image.open(resized_image).show()` and the image appears to be resized and correct.

Comment: So when i use `resized_image.getvalue()` it complains that a string doesn't have a read() method.

Comment: I am wondering if the request.file from flask has a special way of implementing `read()` I hope it is easier than that.

Comment: Try with a real file instead of the `io.BytesIO`. If that works it's clearly a `io.BytesIO` matching issue, which is what I suspect. I can't test myself as I'm using neither  flex env nor flask...

Comment: @DanCornilescu so I tried creating the file with `f = open('resized_image.jpg', 'w+b')` saving the file `image.save(f, format='jpeg')`, test that it shows correctly `Image.open(f).show()` which it does, but still no success. Bucket still shows that file uploaded is 0B and is not visible. Thank you so much for helping by the way.

Comment: And if you call `blob.upload_from_file()` with `f`'s handle?

Comment: @DanCornilescu Yes I call blob.upload_from_file(f). I am thinking about just writing another route that will resize the file then post to the upload_photo handler.

Comment: K, so the problem actually lies in opening and writing the blob. But I don't see it, the code seems to follow the example: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-storage#application_code

Comment: Yeah. I have spent way too much time on this now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I will probably just use an API such as kraken.io

Comment: I have raised an issue in the github repository @DanCornilescu https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/3655

Comment: @DanCornilescu turns out the problem was that I was not setting the file object to point back to the beginning. All i need to have was a `file_object.seek(0)` before I used the upload_from_file() method. I wrapped this in a with statement to ensure the file was deleted afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be out of luck, the images service is not available outside the standard environment.

From the [Migrating Services from the Standard Environment to the Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating#images):

> The Images service is not available outside of the standard
>   environment. However, you can easily serve images directly from your
>   application or directly from Cloud Storage.
>
> If you need to do image processing, you can install and use any image
>   processing library such as [Pillow](https://python-pillow.org/).
>
> The Images service also provided functionality to avoid dynamic
>   requests to your application by handling image resizing using a
>   serving URL. If you want similar functionality, you can generate the
>   re-sized images ahead of time and upload them to Cloud Storage for
>   serving. Alternatively, you could use a third-party content delivery
>   network (CDN) service that offers image resizing.
>
> For more resources, see the following guides:
>
> - [Using Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-storage)
> - [Serving Static Files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/serving-static-files)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You answered me it fully. I have edited the question and stated what happens when I use Pillow. Could you help with this part of the question?